# Display route in Android Google Map

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

Since google disabled the kml output, i dont know how to display route beetween two geopoint using JSON. can someone help me?

Comment: I tried it using xml, i can post the code if you want

Answer (score 0):

Options for generating driving directions are:

1. the [Google Maps API v3 directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)
2. the [Google Maps API web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

The web service will return [JSON](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON).

Comment: i read this article already but how to parse it, so it can be use in android aplication.